# Simplified rolling tire problem - hollow shell vs solid?

Tags: energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics

First off, I don't understand the math formatting thing on here, but none of these formulae are too complicated. 
Take a tire rolling down a hill with angle t and distance d. Modeling it as a hollow shell with no thickness with $I = MR^2$, I got velocity at the bottom $v = \sqrt{gd*sin(t)}$, using energy, which is correct. However, a solid cylinder with $I = \frac{1}{2}MR^2$, I got $\sqrt{2gd*sin(t)}$, which apparently isn't. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are wrong,
Hint:

$\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 + \frac{1}{2}Mv^2 = Mgd\sin(t)$

$wr=v$

Comment: The first one gave me a correct velocity. Also, the potential energy on the right part should have a mass?

Comment: Yes, You wont get \sqrt{2gd*sin(t)} if you use the above formula

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Algebra mistake. Horrible algebra mistake.